# While Loop true and false for approximation of roots

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I'm a bit new to programming, and I'm trying to create a root-approximating code.  Namely, I'm doing something similar to Newton's method in calculus.  The idea is, I'm going to input in a big value, subtract until I know I've passed the root, and then add a smaller quantity until I've passed the root, and iterate until I'm in some comfortable error region.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
def approx(a,b,i):
    while ((1/2)**i) >= (1/2)**10:
        while (another function is true):
            modify values, record root = r
        while (the same function above is false):
            modify values, record root = r
    return approx(a,b,i+1)
return(a,b,r)
```

This does not seem to work in Python, so I was wondering if anyone could point me in the correct direction.

Edit: included my actual code:

```
from fractions import *
from math import sqrt
from math import fabs

def pweight(c,d):
  if d > c:
    return pweight(d,c)
  else:
    return [c+d,c,d]

def eweight(a,b):
  if a == b:
    return [a]
  elif b > a:
    return eweight(b,a)
  else:
    return [b] + eweight(a-b,b)
    def weight(a,b,c,d):
      if a*b/2 > c*d:
        print("No Embedding Exists")
        return (False)
      else:
        return (True, [c+d]+sorted((pweight(c,d) + eweight(a,b))[1:], reverse=True))
    def wgt(a,b,c,d):
      return ([c+d]+sorted((pweight(c,d) + eweight(a,b))[1:], reverse=True))



def red(a,i,k):
  d=a[0]-a[1]-a[2]-a[3]
  if any(item < 0 for item in a[1:]):
    # print ("No Embedding Exists")
    return (False, i)
  elif d >= 0:
    # print ("Embedding Exists! How many iterations?")
    # print(i)
    return (True, i)
  elif d<0:
    a=[a[0]+d,a[1]+d,a[2]+d,a[3]+d]+a[4:]
    a=[a[0]]+sorted(a[1:],reverse=True)
    k.append(a)
    i=i+1
    return red(a,i,k)
def works(a,b):
  L = sqrt(a/(2*b))
  w = weight(1,a,L,L*b)
  return w[0] and red(w[1],0,[])

def inf(a,b,i):
  while ((1/2)**(i+1)) >= (1/2)**(10)):
      while works(a,b):
        a = a - (1/2)**i
        L = sqrt(a/(2*b))
      while not works(a,b):
        a = a + (1/2)**(i+1)
        L = sqrt(a/(2*b))
      return inf(a,b,i+1)
  return (a,b,L)
```

I want to input in "inf(9,1,0)" and have this code return something close to (255/32,1,sqrt(255/64)).  The main problem is the "while works(a,b):" and "while not works(a,b):" in the function "inf(a,b,i)."  I want the function to alternate between the "while works" and "while not works" until i=9.

Any sort of general idea would be appreciated (namely, how do you do some sort of alternating function within a while loop).

Comment: "this does not seem to work" is not a useful problem statement. Can you tell us what it does, and what you expect it to do? You've written pseudo-code above, so it's obviously not executable...what code did you try and find that it didn't work?

Comment: Well it won't work because it's pseudocode. Please give a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Included my actual code, I just wanted a general idea of how to encode two branches in a while statement.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: @roganjosh 3.6.1

Comment: `weight` is defined locally to `eweight`, it can't be accessed from `works`. And `wgt` is never called at all, why is it defined?

Comment: You have a `return` statement in your `while` loop. That exits from the loop immediately, the loop never repeats.

Comment: **I want to alternate ... until i=9.** You never update `i`, how will it ever become 9?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alternate between them, don't put them each in their own `while` loops, put

```
while i < 9:
    if works(a, b):
        do something
    if not works(a, b):
        do something else
```

And whatever you test in your `while` conditions needs to be something that changes somewhere in the loop. Otherwise you'll get an infinite loop.